# how to debug opencart project ? for example putting break points step into code etc?

Tags: debugging, opencart, breakpoints

I'm new one to opencart.is there any debug tools available for opencart ? .i don't know control flow of opencart execution.so i want to put break points,step into code,see variable values. please give any reference to that .thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a super simple little function for the loader class that I use 100 times a day.  It really helps and you can call it from just about anywhere.

OPEN:

`system/engine/loader.php`

Right before the closing brace for the class add this method:

```
// adding testing method
public function test ($items, $quit = true) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($items);
    echo "</pre>";

    if ($quit):
        exit;
    endif;
}
```

Now anytime after the Controller is instantiated you can call:

`$this->load->test($results);`

OR:

`$this->load->test($results, false);`

if you're in a loop and don't want the script to exit.

Obviously substitute `$results` for whatever array or variable you want to test.

It's been a huge help to me.

You can of course add this via vqmod if you don't want to modify the core.

Comment: This helps. Not perhaps as an actual answer to the question, but it does help in debugging. At least me at that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Opencart is very simple system.
In addition you can use [xDebug](http://xdebug.org/) - very useful tool.
Also, read system/logs/error.txt

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // very helpful
die(print_r($_POST, true)); // print all POST data and break the code
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://github.com/mithereal/opencart_inline_debuggers and just d($var); in the source where var is a varible or object